# MySQL. Rearrange column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Having this table, where one `message` should be sent in a specific order (`stepNumber`):

```
CREATE TABLE `t_test` (
  `message` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stepNumber` int DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_1` (`message`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_2` (`stepNumber`)
) 

INSERT INTO t_test VALUES
('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',4),('e',5),('f',6),('g',7),('h',8),('i',9),('j',10)
```

[image]

What I want is to change the order in which any message is sent. I know in advance:

- The `message` I want to update (and of course its current `stepNumber`)
- The new `stepNumber` I want for that `message`

How can I easily rearrange the `stepNumber` field?
For example, If I need the `message` "c" to get postponed to `stepNumber` 8. I need something like this:

[image]

And in the other way, If I need the `message` "i" to get advanced to `stepNumber` 2. I need something like this:

[image]

An update statement is not enough I guess. I was thinking in a procedure.
Maybe I need to create the table in other way?
Thanks!

Comment: The columns `message` and `stepNumber` are not defined as unique (only their combination is unique). Does this mean that there may exist more than one rows with mesage = 'c' and/or stepNumber = 3?

Comment: Correct. It could be possible

Comment: Does this mean that you know in advance the message and stepNumber for the row that you want to update?

Comment: Yes, I know the message and the new stepNumber in advance.

Comment: Why not the current stepNumber? If you don't know it then you can't update it since there may exist more than 1 rows with the same message and different stepNumber.

Comment: Yes you do. You know the message, its original stepNumber, and of course the new stepNumber.

Comment: So you do know the original stepNumber. This is what I asked.

Comment: In your first example you want to change (c,3) to (c,8). What if there are additional rows in the table like (m,4), (n,5), (o,6), ...? Their stepNumbers are the same as the rows that must be updated. Should they be updated? if not then why? Edit your question and clarify.

Comment: I did. Hope it helps!. There was some missing information due to translation from my main goal to a MWE. Sorry for that!.

Comment: In my first comment I asked if: "...there may exist more than one rows with mesage = 'c' and/or stepNumber = 3" and you answered: "Correct. It could be possible" Now I see that you edited the question and defined both columns as unique!

Answer (score 0):

To increase stepnumber c, 3 to c, 8

```
UPDATE t_test SET stepNumber = IF(stepNumber = 3, 8, stepNumber - 1)
WHERE stepNumber BETWEEN 3 AND 8
```

To decrease stepnumber i, 9 to i, 2

```
UPDATE t_test SET stepNumber = IF(stepNumber = 9, 2, stepNumber + 1)
WHERE stepNumber BETWEEN 2 AND 9
```

Comment: It does not work because the unique key.